# Upgrade solr 4.10 index to solr 5.5

Tags: solr4, solr5

I am trying to upgrade a current solr 4.10.4 setup to solr 5.5.5. Does anyone knows how do I upgrade the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the IndexUpgrader tool. More details here:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html

And in the migration doc:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/MIGRATE.html

Comment: where is this lucene-core.jar located?

Comment: core/lucene-core.jar-x.y.z.jar

Comment: thanks! is it suppose to be run when solr is stopped or something?

Comment: Yes the index shouldn't be modified during the upgrade.

Comment: I got this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not load codec 'Lucene410'.  Did you forget to add lucene-backward-codecs.jar?`

Comment: Try adding lucene-backward-codecs.jar to your classpath. The jar should be included in the directory tree.

Comment: Strange, I still faced the same problem. Is it because I use lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.5.jar? Should I be using 4.10 codecs?

Comment: you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237232/unable-to-run-solr-5-index-upgrader

Comment: @Moses Liao GZ did you found the solution for this??